# Jars needed for Objectify4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

We have a legacy system that was just ported to AppEngine. So now we need to use Objectify4, however the legacy application we have is not yet *"mavenized"* so we add jars manually. What are all the jarts needed to be placed in `WEB-INF/lib` folder so `Objectify` jars and its depenedencies will work.

The current AppEngine version we set in the classpath is 1.7.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quoting from Objectify documentation:

> Add objectify-N.N.N.jar to your project's WEB-INF/lib directory. There are no other jar dependencies.

Edit: The jars are located in the Maven Repository, by browsing the source. For example, [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/?repo=maven#git/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/4.0a4%253Fstate%253Dclosed) you can find the objectify-4.0a4.jar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah but where do you get the jars.  That is the question.  They are not available at http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/downloads/list

Answer (score 3):

You can download the builds from the Maven repo here:

> https://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/maven/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/

That being said, there doesn't appear to be any guarantee with these files so use at your own discretion.

Depending on when how soon you plan to deploy your product, it may make more sense to build your service using v3 as opposed to v4 for now.